# R Iterate through list of dates and filter a dataframe by each of them

Tags: r, date

I have a list of dates

```
library(tidyverse)

it.date <- as.Date("2022-03-31") %m+% months(0:12)
```

and a sample dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(id = seq(1:10), date = as.Date("2022-03-31") %m+% months(1:10))
```

what I would like to do is loop through the data frame and filter by each date in the it.date variable.

I have tried

```
v.list <- lapply(it.date, function(x) subset(df, df$date<= it.date)
```

and

```
v.list <- list()
for(i in it.date){
  new.df <- subset(df, df$date<= it.date[i])
  v.list <- c(v.list, list(new.df))
  return(v.list)
}
```

neither of which has worked for me.

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this is what you wanted `lapply(it.date, function(x) df[x <= df$date,])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your `lapply()` call should use `x`, not `it.date`.

```
v.list <- lapply(it.date, function(x) subset(df, date <= x))
```